# MATLAB - list all methods supplied by subclass only?

Tags: oop, matlab

I have a class that inherits from multiple superclasses, and I would like to get the methods that the class has. Naively using `methods()` returns methods from the class I'm working with as well as superclass methods, but I'm not interested in the superclass methods.

Any idea how to do this? I couldn't find anything in MATLAB documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using new style MCOS classes (with classdef files), or old style classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your subclass doesn't reimplement any of the methods of the superclasses (or if you're fine with ignoring reimplemented methods), you can use the functions [METHODS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/methods.html) and [SUPERCLASSES](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/superclasses.html) to find a list of subclass methods that aren't also methods of any of the superclasses. For example:

```
>> obj = 'hgsetget';  %# A sample class name
>> supClasses = superclasses(obj)

supClasses = 

    'handle'    %# Just one superclass, but what follows should handle more

>> supMethods = cellfun(@methods,supClasses,...  %# Find methods of superclasses
                        'UniformOutput',false);
>> supMethods = unique(vertcat(supMethods{:}));  %# Get a unique list of
                                                 %#   superclass methods
>> subMethods = setdiff(methods(obj),supMethods)  %# Find methods unique to the
                                                  %#   subclass
subMethods = 

    'get'
    'getdisp'
    'set'
    'setdisp'
```

Comment: I was hoping there was an elegant built-in to do this with, but I kind of figured that this type of solution is what it would come down to. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Even though this question is solved, let me add another answer using `meta.class` capabilities:

```
%# some class name
clname = 'hgsetget';

%# obtain class meta-info
mt = meta.class.fromName(clname);

%# get name of class defining each method
cdef = arrayfun(@(c)c.Name, [mt.MethodList.DefiningClass], 'Uniform',false);

%# keep only methods that are defined in the subclass
subMethods = {mt.MethodList(ismember(cdef,clname)).Name}
```

The result for this example:

```
subMethods = 
    'set'    'get'    'setdisp'    'getdisp'    'empty'
```

Note how the result also includes the static methods `empty` which all non-abstract classes have (used to create an empty array of that class).

Comment: You can also get the metaclass using the class operator '?', as in "mt = ?hgsetget".